# making a simple timer in C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm still new to c# and i dont how to invoke the method updateTime() every ten seconds

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    TextView timerViewer;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        timerViewer = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.textView1);

        // i need to invoke this every ten seconds
        updateTimeinViewer();
    }

    protected void updateTimeinViewer(){
        // changes the textViewer
    }
}
```

if there's a way to create a new Thread or something similar, i would be please to get some help.

I'm using Xamarin Studio

Comment: C != C# ... I've fixed your tag.

Answer (score 7):

**1** - One usual way to do that in C# is to use a [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), like so:

```
int count = 1;
TextView timerViewer;
private System.Threading.Timer timer;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    timerViewer = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

    timer = new Timer(x => UpdateView(), null, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
}

private void UpdateView()
{
    this.RunOnUiThread(() => timerViewer.Text = string.Format("{0} ticks!", count++));
}
```

Notice that you need to use `Activity.RunOnUiThread()` in order to avoid cross-thread violations when accessing UI elements.

---

**2** - Another, cleaner approach is to make use of C#'s [Language-level support for asynchrony](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx), which removes the need to manually marshal back and forth to the UI thread:

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        timerViewer = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        RunUpdateLoop();
    }

    private async void RunUpdateLoop()
    {
        int count = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            timerViewer .Text = string.Format("{0} ticks!", count++);
        }
    }
```

Notice there's no need for `Activity.RunOnUiThread()` here. the C# compiler figures that out automatically.

Comment: how would I stop the timer in version 2?

Comment: @derekantrican change `while(true)` for `while(someCondition)` and switch the condition on/off.

Comment: the problem with that is that if the timer ticks over just before you click a "stop" button, it will still be in the `await Task.Delay(1000);` line and will tick to the next second *then* stop. I can add something like `if(someCondition)` also after the `await Task.Delay(1000);` line......but is there a better way?