# Update label text with timer on UI Thread, without blocking the UI

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a label that i want to update with every 10 sec. Unfortunately, as it is right now, the event blocks the UI which means that i can't interact with the application.

I tried to make a new Thread, to run the task, but the application tells me that I can't make UI specific changes from a non-main thread.

The code is as follows:

```
Public partial class FrontPage : ContentPage
{
    public FrontPage()
    {
        updateLabel();
    }
    updateLabel()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            test.Text = i;
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Since I need to run this asyncronously in order to not block the UI, I suspect that the solution involves await/async operators. Unfortunately i'm not sure how to implement it, in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to understand how i can run a method on my UI thread, and still interact with the UI. Therefore, using a Timer is not a possibility in this case i'm afraid.

You can use a thread (via `Task.Run`) and then use `Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync` or `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` to execute UI updates within that "background" thread:

```
Task.Run(async() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
        {
            test.Text = i;
        });
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        i++;
    }
});
```

Note: Also do not use `Thread.Sleep` as that will hang the entire thread, including its message pump (a really bad thing when it is the UI/main thread).

Comment: What is the point of using `async` and `await` if you're not going to actually take advantage of it? It would be much better to just remove the `Task.Run()` and the `await Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync()`. The `await Task.Delay(10000);` will yield the thread back to the caller, and when the delay expires, the method will continue running in the main thread, just as desired. You don't need all that other stuff.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The whole point it to remove as much processing from the Main/UI thread as possible and in a mobile env. w/ multi-core|large|small-core scheduling, consuming Main/UI thread cycles comes with producing "laggie" apps, UI yank, higher battery usage, etc...

Comment: @PeterDuniho And he is not looking for a "Timer" solution... see his comments in the other answer.

Comment: Uh, your code above doesn't do _anything_ to address any of what you describe. Indeed, it makes such problems _worse_ because it adds new transitions between threads, and additional objects. The fact that the OP wants a "non-timer" solution doesn't excuse the extra layers of useless thread-switching your suggestion has.

Comment: See the non-timer example, the second suggestion in [this answer for the marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25212213). It shows what your answer _should_ have been (ignoring for a moment that your answer never should have been in the first place, given how easily found the duplicate question was).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Well, I will totally disagree with your statement, my perspective is from practical usage to benchmarking UI yank on 100s of mobile devices over 10 years (in a testing suite, we have access to 1000+ Android|iOS devices, so yea, I would absolutely not do it the way you are describing...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198088/discussion-between-sushihangover-and-peter-duniho).

Answer (score -2):

use a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8) instead, and use [BeginInvokeOnMainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.begininvokeonmainthread?view=xamarin-forms) to force execution of UI updates on the UI thread

```
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
t.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
t.AutoReset = true;
t.Enabled = true;

private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( () => {
    test.Text = i;
    i++;
  });
}
```

Comment: This is just an example I made up, to understand how i can run a method on my UI thread, and still interact with the UI. Therefore, using a Timer is not a possibility in this case i'm afraid.

Comment: "use BeginInvokeOnMainThread to force execution of UI updates on the UI thread"